# greedy and non-greedy regex aren't enough at all

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a problem matching some stuff out of a string the problem is with
( re.findall() ) and it only allows me to match greedy or non-greedy and I want to match the things between greedy and non-greedy for example:

```
import re
text = "f(s(5)+5)+f(12)"
regex = re.findall("f\(.*\)", text)

>>>['f(s(5)+5)+f(12)']
```

this is greedy and will match the whole string.
another example:

```
import re
text = "f(s(5)+5)+f(12)"
regex = re.findall("f\(.*?\)", text)

>>>['f(s(5)', 'f(12)']
```

this is non-greedy and will match some parts but not enough 
i want to match all greedy and non-greedy and the matches between them like

```
>>> ['f(s(5)', 'f(s(5)+5)', 'f(12), 'f(s(5)+5)+f(12)']
```

see there is one match missing from the non-greedy and greedy ones it is
'f(s(5)+5)' and it would be more than one missing if the string is larger.

Comment: General math expressions are not regular language. You need stronger means than regular expressions--regular language.

Comment: Regex isn't the right tool for this job.  You need some sort of parser.

Comment: okay, any suggestions about any library that could help to build a parser for this job. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: if you can provide more clear instructions, we should be able to figure out the required regex. Do you want to capture everything between 'f(' and ')', including all subpatterns?

Comment: yeah exactly what i want @dhanlin

Comment: If you want to solve this with regular expressions, you'd need recursive regexes. I don't know wether regular expressions in python 3 provide that feature.

Comment: You want to match from first `(` until and including the symmetrically matching `)`, don't you? I.e. the goal is to find the end of the expression which starts with the first `(`.

Comment: Can you make an assumption on how deep the nested `()` get at most? If not regex is not your tool. E.g. the first part of your example I'd call 2 deep. The last part 1 deep.

Comment: Some long time ago I used [pyggy](https://pypi.org/project/pyggy/). It seems dead now. Looking at Python parser packages [list](https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing), [modgrammar](https://pypi.org/project/modgrammar/) looks decent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah like everyone already told, there is no direct regex that would give you the desired output.

But with a loop on regex, i was able to achieve your desired output. See if it helps.

```
import re
text = "f(s(5)+5)+f(12)"
print ("occurences of ')' : {}".format(text.count(")")))

test_str = text
# loop repeatedly until all substrings starting with 'f(' are parsed
while test_str:
    # for loop: to parse all ')'
    for i in range(1,test_str.count(")")+1):
        # regex explanation can be found @ https://regex101.com/r/jJOXr0/1/
        regex = r'^f\((?:.*?\)){' + re.escape(str(i)) + r'}'
        output_list = re.findall(regex, test_str)
        print(output_list[0])

    # find the next substring starting with 'f('
    substr_id = test_str.find('f(',1)
    if substr_id == -1:
        break
    else:
        test_str = test_str[substr_id:]


Output :
occurences of ')' : 3
f(s(5)
f(s(5)+5)
f(s(5)+5)+f(12)
f(12)
```